# Core Date Concept: NSFetchedResultsController vs. NSManagedObject objectsWithFetchRequest

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

When do I use a [NSFetchedResultsController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) in comparsion to the [objectsWithFetchRequest](http://restkit.org/api/0.10.0/Categories/NSManagedObject+ActiveRecord.html#//api/name/objectsWithFetchRequests%3a) method in NSManagedObject? Are there typical scenarios?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`objectsWithFetchRequest:` (or `executeFetchRequest:error:`) just executes a fetch request and returns the result set.

A `NSFetchedResultsController` executes a fetch request and then monitors changes to the data store (or more precisely, changes to the managed object context). If objects are added/deleted/modified that cause the result set of the fetch request to change, it calls delegate functions to report the change.

A `NSFetchedResultsController` is in most cases used to populate a *table view* with the result of a fetch request, and automatically update the table view if objects are inserted, deleted or changed.